# Reorganize index and column DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm supposed to create a palindrome checker and convert them into dataFrame.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd 
# TODO: Check if the number is palindrome or not and convert them into DataFrame
n = [1,0,1] 
g = n == n[::-1]

a = pd.DataFrame(n)
a['Is Palindrome'] = g
a.transpose()
```

The Output:

```
                0       1       2
0               3       0       3
Is Palindrome   True    True    True
```

But the output I want the DataFrame to print is:

```
  0     1    2   Is Palindrome
  3     0    3   True
```

How do I build that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

You could use pandas to do it:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Number'],data=[101,202,301])
df['Palindrome']=[str(i)==str(i)[::-1] for i in df['Number']]

print(df)

   Number  Palindrome
0     101        True
1     202        True
2     301       False
```

Or if you want to transpose it:

```
print(df.T)
               0     1      2
Number       101   202    301
Palindrome  True  True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add the `Is Palindrome` column all the way at the end:

```
import pandas as pd 

n = [3,0,3] 
g = n == n[::-1]
a = pd.DataFrame(n)
a = a.transpose()
a['Is Palindrome'] = g
```

Comment: It'd be useful to have the output as well